# How to handle connection failure for subscription on WebSphere queue?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

When a .net windows service is connected to Websphere MQ queue for subscription and keeps reading messages, how can we handle the issues like network disconnect or some thing wrong happened, can we rely on `MQQueueManager.IsConnected` property all the time? This article is confusing me: [IC75673: MQQueueManager.IsConnected property is "true" after the connection is broken in a .NET application.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC75673)

Below is the code I have to read messages from the queue and I am using MQ Version 8.0

```
private MQQueueManager _queueManager;
private MQQueue _queue;
private MQTopic _topic;
public bool isSubscribed = false;

public void Subscribe()
{
    var queueManagerName = "myQueueManager";
    var properties = new Hashtable();
    //Set all the properties here
    _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);

    //Conect to Queue
    _queue = _queueManager.AccessQueue("devQueue", MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF);

    isSubscribed = true;
    while (isSubscribed)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            isSubscribed = false;
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        try
        {
            Receive(onMessageReceived);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
        }
    }   
}


public override void Receive<T>(Action<T> onMessageReceived)
{
    try
    {
        var dataReceived = new MQMessage();
        _queue.Get(dataReceived);

        T message;
        message = (T)(object)dataReceived;

        onMessageReceived(message);     
        _queueManager.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APAR IC75673 that you linked to was fixed in a version 7.0.1.6 of MQ which was released [Aug 01 2011](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27014224#7016).  MQ v8.0 was released [June 13 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ibm-mq/info).  In general any fixed in a prior version of MQ will also be fixed in a new release.

Does your application connect to a queue manager on the same Windows server where the application is running?  In your code you do not specify things like a hostname, port, channel name, etc that would indicate you are using a MQ Client connection over the network.  It is possible you could be using the MQSERVER or MQCHLLIB/MQCHLTAB environment variables provide the connectivity details.

If your app makes a local connection to the queue manager it is using what is called "binding mode" and does not rely on the network.  The IsConnected method be a good indication you are still connected.  The documentation states that if your connection is idle the status provided is the last known status when the last activity was performed (Get, Put, etc).

If your app is making a MQ Client connection over the network then the time that it takes the client to notice a broken connection depends on the HBINT that is negotiated between the queue manager and the MQ client.  For .NET it appears that you would need to use a MQ channel table to set this value.  @Morag Hughson answer to StackOverflow question "[WebSphere MQ - Changing channel definition structure using XMS.NET API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142127/websphere-mq-changing-channel-definition-structure-using-xms-net-api/26151643#26151643)" provides some more detail.  You can also look at my answer to StackOverflow question "[Setting timeout for IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040817/setting-timeout-for-ibm-mq/41456301#41456301)" for more detail on how the HBINT impacts the TIMEOUT of a client channel.